# How to build Python as a shared dynamic library?

Tags: python, compilation, shared-libraries, dynamic-linking

I tried many things but I was not able to get this working.

I need to build Python as a shared dynamic lib (on OSX). So when I run the `otool -L` on any of the components, I need to see that the dylib is linked.

For example:

```
$ otool -L $HOME/.pyenv/versions/2.7.11/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_ctypes.so
/Users/foo/.pyenv/versions/2.7.11/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_ctypes.so:
    /Users/foo/.pyenv/versions/2.7.11/lib/libpython2.7.dylib (compatibility version 2.7.0, current version 2.7.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1226.10.1)
```

This example above is from a different approach (that is not working as well). However, this demonstrates (I guess), how a successfully linked Python should be looking like.

No matter what I have tried, my `otool -L` output looks like this:

```
otool -L _ctypes.so
_ctypes.so:
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1252.50.4)
```

I do not see the dynamic lib file `libpython2.7.dylib` being linked. The file exists in the folder above though.

Here is my build command:

```
/configure --prefix=/Users/me/apps/python2.7.15-clang-1000.10.44 --enable-shared --enable-unicode=ucs2 CFLAGS="-arch x86_64" LDFLAGS="-arch x86_64"
```

I guess, because I am building to a custom location, the linker fails to find the dynamic library file.

I tried many things, tweaking `$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH`, passing various `LD_` flags, with no success so far.

### Update

So I tried this on another computer, a Linux machine that has a shared dynamic Python, and I can confirm that both the `python` binary and the `.so` files have links to the `libpython2.7` file.

```
ldd /usr/lib64/python2.7/lib-dynload/_ctypes.so
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffd4a5dd000)
    libffi.so.6 => /lib64/libffi.so.6 (0x00007f443bf1e000)
    libpython2.7.so.1.0 => /lib64/libpython2.7.so.1.0 (0x00007f443bb52000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f443b935000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f443b572000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f443b36e000)
    libutil.so.1 => /lib64/libutil.so.1 (0x00007f443b16a000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00007f443ae68000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x0000558a69696000)
```

and the actual `python` bin looks like this:

```
ldd /usr/bin/python
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff1850f000)
    libpython2.7.so.1.0 => /lib64/libpython2.7.so.1.0 (0x00007f839c1a5000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f839bf89000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f839bd84000)
    libutil.so.1 => /lib64/libutil.so.1 (0x00007f839bb81000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00007f839b87f000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f839b4bb000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x0000556816d12000)
```

So now I am absolutely sure that I am missing something.

Comment: What approach produced the correct output you included in your question?

Comment: It is an explanation posted here: https://github.com/macvim-dev/macvim/wiki/Python-2.x-and-Python-3.x But even with that, I am not getting that `otool -L` output :(

Comment: The main question is, do I need to pass a `-L` flag pointing to TO-BE generated `libpython2.7.dylib`file?